# how to properly use Mysql to SELECT * FROM table WHERE column='Any_value_in_Array'

Tags: php, mysql, join

Okay so I'm basically a noob when it comes to setting up tables and querying them ... but I think My title explains what I'm trying to do pretty well and I believe I'm looking for a way to use a `JOIN` but for the life of me can't figure out exactly how to do it (I've read some examples on S.O. and tutorials around the web but haven't been able to wrap my head around it). Basically I have a table called `userFollowsSeries` which has three columns

```
 | userID | seriesID | series_title |
 ------------------------------------
 |   int  |  int     |    var_char  |
```

and another table `series` that has a primary key `seriesID` and a bunch of relevant information about the series. Now I want to get all Information in table `series` for each  `seriesID` for a user.

Now I'm basically trying to get each `seriesID` based on a single `userID` like this

```
$userFollows = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM userFollowsSeries WHERE userID='$user_id'") or die(mysql_error());
while($follows = mysqli_fetch_array($userFollows)){
    $show_id=$follows['seriesID'];
    echo $show_id;  //this is realy just here for testing 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM series WHERE id='$show_id'") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          // i get and print out everything in a formatted for my html code 
     }
 }
```

now I realize that this is less then ideal and is not very efficient but can't figure out how to do all of this in one statement/query using again i presume some sort of `JOIN` statement. Everything I have Works but is just really slow (presumably because of the query embeded in the while loop). Anyway's you can help me out with how a join or new table structure to improve this would be awesome and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of `` SELECT * FROM `series` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `SeriesID` FROM `userFollowsSeries` WHERE `userID`=$user_id) `` should work nicely. Just be aware that it may not make good use of indexes. It may be better to select the IDs, build an array of them, then use IN with implode to join the array.

Comment: thanks for the answer ... when you say "may not good make of use of indexes" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Well, MySQL uses indexes to search for data. This method may not be compatible with that. You should try putting `EXPLAIN` before the query, and see what it lists.

Comment: okay awesome .. I will look into the EXPLAIN method a little more as I'm sure it will come up useful in the future, But everything seems to work perfectly(minus some formating not posted here) thanks for the help! +1

Answer (score 0):

A JOIN basically glues two tables together on a column. Take this as an example:

```
SELECT * FROM userFollowsSeries INNER JOIN series ON (userFollowsSeries.seriesID = series.seriesID)
```

What we're doing here is, in effect, selecting everything from the userFollowsSeries, then for each record, attaching the row from the series table which satisfies the condition in the ON clause.

Comment: hey thanks for the help, i tried the code out with no luck this returns the mysqli_result as a false meaning something went wrong, but  not exactly sure a s to what

Comment: Your query misses the WHERE statement, it has to include `userID` = $userID at WHERE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM userFollowsSeries ufs
    INNER JOIN series s
        ON s.id = ufs.seriesID
    WHERE ufs.userID = {$user_id}
```

and you should make a foreign key or an index on field seriesID of table userFollowsSeries.